# Excel VBA Creating new cells based on cell data

Tags: excel, vba, cells

so I'm looking to create something that will create X amount of cells when "X" is entered into the corresponding cell, then fill those cell with numbers counting up to X.

Since I'm unable to input pictures, I created a rough example of what I'm trying to achieve.

*How the table will start off*

...|........A........|.............B...............|..........C........

1.|..................| **Enter data below**.|

2.|**Question 1**| _______________|

3.|**Question 2**| _______________|

4.|**Question 3**| _______________|

*Entering the data, ("Question 1" has no effect, but once Question 2"B3" is entered it will create cells)*

...|........A........|.............B...............|..........C........

1.|..................| **Enter data below**.|

2.|**Question 1**| _____Answer____|

3.|**Question 2**| _______3_______|     **<---------------**

4.|**Question 3**| _______________|

*Then an amount of cells will be created base on the amount entered into "B3"*

...|........A........|.............B...............|..........C........

1.|..................| **Enter data below**.|

2.|**Question 1**| _____Answer____|

3.|**Question 2**| _______3_______|

4.|**Q1..............**| _______________|    **<---------------**

5.|**Q2..............**| _______________|    **<---------------**

6.|**Q3..............**| _______________|    **<---------------**

7.|**Question 3**| _______________|

If anyone could help out that would be much appreciated. Feel free to ask for any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into the worksheet module you are interested in :

```
Public InModif As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If InModif = True Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
InModif = True

Dim NbInsert As Integer

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        NbInsert = CInt(Target.Value)
        Do While NbInsert <> 0
            Rows(Target.Offset(1, 0).Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Target.Offset(1, 0).Value = NbInsert
            Target.Offset(1, -1).Value = "Q" & NbInsert
            NbInsert = NbInsert - 1
        Loop
    Else
    End If
Else
End If

InModif = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```